# Centering image css/html

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having a problem centering an image in css,

I have this:

```
<div class="workcontainer3">
  <div class="wc3_inside"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.workcontainer3 {
  display:box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left:341px;
  margin-top:277px;
  background-color: #68477c;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(50deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(60deg) rotateZ(-45deg);
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wc3_inside{ 
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  content:url(../testeimg.jpg) 50% 50%;
}
```

So basicaly I want to create a site, when i'll go to publish articles with images, and I want to get that image and independently of his size, i want that the image become centered in the" rhombus workcontainer3".
Like this:

[image]

So anyone knows what i'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Is it possible to include the image via HTML `<img>` instead over css `content`?

Comment: thanks for the reply! Yes, but still dont resolve the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your html, but you could try this, assuming your `.wc3_inside` is inside `.workcontainer3`.

```
.workcontainer3 {
  display: table;
}

.wc3_inside {
    display: table-cell;    
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8xeG/)

Comment: I'm using html like this:   

<div class="workcontainer3">
 <div class="wc3_inside"></div>
</div>

Comment: well that didnt work, it increased the original size of workcontainer3 and the object inside is still not centered, but thanks for the reply :) Its a try

Comment: That's what I assumed. Does my solution help you? Did you take a look at the fiddle I created?

Comment: It increases the size of `.workcontainer3`, because you gave `.wc3_inside` a max height/width of 500px in contrast to the 300px of  `.workcontainer3`.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks :) Well, to center i add to your code this:   width:100%;, and it become centered. But one thing i wanted to was that the image inside was bigger than the workcontainer because i dont want to see any inner parts of the work container